# Separation of year, month and day in an 8-digit number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I am new to Python/pandas.
I have a data frame that looks like this

```
x = pd.DataFrame([20210901,20210902, 20210903, 20210904])
```

[out]:

```
          0
0  20210901
1  20210902
2  20210903
3  20210904
```

I want to separate each row as follows: For example

```
year = 2021
month = 9
day = 1
```

or I have a list for each row like this:

```
[2021,9,1]
```

Comment: what is the output you are seeking? please add the way you want it to be so we can visualize what is the result you seek

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` to convert the entire column to `datetime` type.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Col': [20210917,20210918, 20210919, 20210920]})
>>>
>>> df.Col = pd.to_datetime(df.Col, format='%Y%m%d')
>>> df
         Col
0 2021-09-17
1 2021-09-18
2 2021-09-19
3 2021-09-20
>>> df['Year'] = df.Col.dt.year
>>> df['Month'] = df.Col.dt.month
>>> df['Day'] = df.Col.dt.day
>>>
>>> df
         Col  Year  Month  Day
0 2021-09-17  2021      9   17
1 2021-09-18  2021      9   18
2 2021-09-19  2021      9   19
3 2021-09-20  2021      9   20
```

If you want the result as list, you can use list comprehension along with `zip` function.

```
>>> [(year, month, day) for year, month, day in zip(df.Year, df.Month, df.Day)]
[(2021, 9, 17), (2021, 9, 18), (2021, 9, 19), (2021, 9, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate each row as follows three new columns: year, month, day

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":[20210901,20210902, 20210903, 20210904]})

# split date field to three fields: year month day 
df["year"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:4])
df["month"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[4:6])
df["day"] = df["date"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[6:])

print(df)
```

result is as following

```
# result is:
 date  year  month  day
0  20210901  2021    09  01
1  20210902  2021    09  02
2  20210903  2021    09  03
3  20210904  2021    09  04
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a simple function which will return a zipped list in the format you wanted

```
def convert_to_dates(df):
         dates = []
         for i,v in x.iterrows():
             dates.append(v.values[0])
         for i in range(len(dates)):
             dates[i] = str(dates[i])
         years = []
         months = []
         days = []
         for i in range(len(dates)):
             years.append(dates[i][0:4])
             months.append(dates[i][4:6])
             days.append(dates[i][6:8])
         return list(zip(years, months, days))
```

Call it by using `convert_to_dates(x)`

Output:

```
In [4]: convert_to_dates(x)
Out[4]:
[('2021', '09', '01'),
 ('2021', '09', '02'),
 ('2021', '09', '03'),
 ('2021', '09', '04')]
```